# Upgrade .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.8 - Web Application Returning 404 Error

Tags: .net-4.5, .net-4.8

I have attempting to upgrade a web application that uses .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.8.

The application runs on a server that both compiles and runs the application, so I installed the .NET Framework 4.8 Developer Pack. I restarted the server and it has booted up successfully.

TeamCity successfully built and compiled the application and Octopus successfully deployed as per usual. However, when I now attempt to access the website, I get a 404 at the login page.

[image]

Looking at the folder structure, the file is definitely there. The code builds and runs successfully on my local machine, allowing me to login and perform any function on the system.

Is there something that I have missed running or doing on the server to get this to work?

***Edit: Request for IIS Configuration***

The configuration of this hasn't changed since I've upgrade the .NET Framework but here is what I have. If this isn't the configuration that is being asked about, please let me know.

*Bindings*
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Everything else has been left as the default values.

Comment: Can you share details of how you've configured your application on IIS? Most likely that's where the issue is

Comment: May be your configuration file is updated locally and that's why it is running. you might have not updated the configuration on remote server. also 4.8 should be enabled (as a system feature) on your remote server

Comment: I am getting the details for the IIS configuration for you now, Shahzad.
I will compare the web.config files now as well, Kamran.

Comment: FREB trace would be good to start with, to understand the root cause. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Comment: Thanks, Abhiman. I'll give it a look.

Comment: So, the server was doing things on Wednesday when this question was posted and I couldn't get onto it to figure out what it was doing to take up 100% CPU and memory. Looking this morning, the website loads successfully, so the server did something to allow the installation to work correctly. Kamran, when I go into the windows features, I don't get the standard window but a wizard that shows categories and stuff. Looking through absolutely everything, there is no option to allow .NET 4.8, only 4.7